# Datasource to Tree structure format of Array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

I was not able to get upto root->countries->states->cities->zones->campuses. I m getting upto root-countries-states only. Please help me to complete this done.

here is the code snippet, i was tried in a basic way of code. Please help me to get this done.

```
function getLocationsTree(locations,cb) {
var rootObj = {};
var cities = [];
var rootObj = _.where(locations, {'locationTypeId': 10000})[0];
var countries = _.where(locations, {locationTypeId: 10028, 
 parentId:rootObj.id.toString()});
var i = 0;
//var countriesData = [];
_.each(countries, function(country, index){
  i++;
  var states = _.where(locations, {locationTypeId: 10029,  parentId:country.id.toString()});
  _.each(states, function(state, index){
     cities = _.where(locations, {locationTypeId: 10030, parentId:state.id.toString()});
      //console.log("cities", cities);
      _.each(cities, function(city, index){
        console.log({locationTypeId: 10031, parentId:city.id.toString()});
      var zones = _.where(locations, {locationTypeId: 10031, parentId:city.id.toString()});
      console.log("zones", zones);
        if(zones.length > 0 ){
          _.each(zones, function(zone, index){
            var campuses = _.where(locations, {locationTypeId: 10032, parentId:zone.id.toString()});
            console.log("campus length", campuses.length);
            if(campuses.length > 0){
              zone.children = campuses;
            }
          });
          city.children = zones;
        }
      });
      console.log("cities",cities);
      states.children = cities;
  });
  country.children = states;
  if (i == countries.length){
    rootObj.children = countries;
    rootObj.childrenCount = countries.length;
    cb(null, rootObj);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please share a full code snippet on jsbin.com.  This is basically impossible to answer because we can't see the data format of your `locations` object.

Comment: I assume `_` is `lodash` ?

Comment: @jnylen Thanks for your prompt response. i m using single location collections for storing all types and here is the jsbin link https://jsbin.com/povabifipi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Please include a _working_ jsbin example _with your data_.

Comment: @AnandUndavia Yes. its lodash only. I m stucked wit this since 2 days. working on this topic more than 10 hours today. My brain is dead.

Comment: @jnylen I m working wit nodejs, i m poor in updating jsbin with Client javascript. But i updated the same link wit the code of what i have written.

Comment: Thanks Guys. spelling mistake. "states.children" should be state.children.